# why does google chrome throw Uncaught ReferenceError: wow is not defined error at my page asp.net?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, google-chrome

I'm working on asp.net website and I'm Using wow.js and animate.css and I defined wow.js in my page master called userMasterpage so when I execute my project by firefox is working fine.but when I execute my project with chrome a long scroll is shown and also an error is appear in the console but the wow animation is working also in chrome the problem is I dont know why  in the console shown  **Uncaught ReferenceError: wow is not defined at Accueil.aspx:33** and shown the scroll although I'm seting `height:auto`

```html
page master 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
        <link href="fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"/>

        <script src="js/wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> new wow().Init(); </script>
```

this the error
[image]

this the scroll problem 
[image]

Comment: Does `js/wow.min.js` get loaded successfully? Is there an object called `wow` in that script file?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new WOW().init()` (`WOW` all uppercase, `init` all lower case) ? At least that is what it says in the documentation of this library https://wowjs.uk/ Maybe you're using some other library.

Comment: yes but i cant edit on this file this the source of this file http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/ ah ok thank u I will try now this by settign WOW uppercase and init lower case

Comment: when i set new WOW().init() (WOW all uppercase, init all lower case) that solve the error of chrome but slow the animation and make the scroll  shown